# I have a collection of user data. I want to query usrname,registered date,no. of users on that particular date?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The below is a collection of Users, it has 5 fields, I want to query `username`, `created_on` and number of users based on the date they registered is based on `created_on` attribute.

for example I need to query users registered on date 03-03-2017 using `created_on` attribute if suppose it contains two users registered that particular date

My query should return `{"user":["user1", "user2"], "num_users":2}`

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("58b955c47ff9182e54bac2e5"),
    "username": "Sanjay",
    "password": "$2a$10$JoLx9R0f1WI23R9i/ieSl.YFFO9Auu.dJBdw4BvRQ/vKqKp9rTv6.",
    "dob": "2121-03-11T18:30:00.000Z",
    "email": "jp@newgmail",
    "created_on": ISODate("2017-03-03T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "__v": 0
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("58b956107ff9182e54bac2e6"),
    "username": "rahul",
    "password": "$2a$10$Z7IRhIORAi9zlXGNewxsceaO66CQr7hg142yMdQilMqKhYwtC/wSm",
    "dob": "1211-02-20T18:30:00.000Z",
    "email": "rahul@gmail.com",
    "created_on": ISODate("2017-03-02T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "__v": 0
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("58b9562b7ff9182e54bac2e7"),
    "username": "ravi",
    "password": "$2a$10$fAqiyM.b9.B7x.LpLaUnnOdCSF.4xj55uSyOD6KLwlXu1W6awM66C",
    "dob": "2017-03-20T18:30:00.000Z",
    "email": "gmail@ravi",
    "created_on": ISODate("2017-03-03T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "__v": 0
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("58ba69fac3285e193089a62b"),
    "username": "prashanth",
    "password": "$2a$10$CPQiRBk5tiUGna8JHmQhhO.a9SYBz0RyDCuFdLdc6IrpAWbw7d/Ua",
    "dob": "1993-02-20T18:30:00.000Z",
    "email": "jprashanthgowda34@gmail.com",
    "created_on": ISODate("2017-03-04T07:17:14.563Z"),
    "__v": 0
}
```

what I am doing is :

```
db.usercollection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$created_on",
        num_user: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

what I need to query is :

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2017-03-02T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "num_user" : 1,
    "users" : ["sanjay"]
}
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2017-03-04T07:17:14.563Z"),
    "num_user" : 1,
    users:["prashanth"]
}
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2017-03-03T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "num_user" : 2,
    "users" : ["rahul", "ravi"];
}
```

Please suggest me solution. If my approach is wrong kindly insist me how could I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) in your aggregation  :

```
db.usercollection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$created_on",
        users: {
            $push: "$username"
        },
        num_user: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

For adding `username` JSONObject inside the `users` array :

```
db.data.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$created_on",
        users: {
            $push: {
                username: "$username"
            }
        },
        num_user: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: it works, thanks!!  i am getting result like this {
    "_id" : ISODate("2017-03-03T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "users" : [ 
        "Sanjay", 
        "ravi"
    ],
    "num_user" : 2.0
}  but what should i do to getresult like, {
    "_id" : ISODate("2017-03-03T11:40:00.692Z"),
    "users" : [{username:"Sanjay"},{username:"ravi"}],
    "num_user" : 2.0
}

Answer (score 0):

Use $push operator in $group stage  aggregate,

```
      db.tr.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            _id: "$created_on",
            user: {
                $push: "$username"
            },
            num_user: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
     }]).pretty()
```